# Tabs as in Android Market

Tags: android, tabs

I develop application with scrollable tabs as in android market or google+ applications. I use two libraries: ViewFlow and http://viewpagerindicator.com/, but this libraries propose tabs that moving too quickly and i need that they move move slowly as in android market.
Can somebody help me? How can i change source code of this libraries  to make tab moving more slowly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ViewPagerIndicator? 
http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use a widget called the [`PagerHeader`](https://github.com/ChainsDD/Superuser/blob/master/src/com/noshufou/android/su/widget/PagerHeader.java) in combination with the [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).